# GL invoke shader and get output colors

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I am not familar with OpenGL but I may want to dive into it if it is possible what I want to do. Basically, I want to write a shader in the GL Shading Language and query this shader for some output values. I've been skimming some online articles and from what I saw, shaders seem to be executed directly by OpenGL and mapped to the geometry.

To make things clear, some *dream code* which I would like to write:

```
// Load the GL shader `shader`
// ...

// GLShaderOutput and glQueryShader are imaginary names

GLShaderOutput out = glQueryShader(shader, /* input parameters */);

// Obtain the received data

Color color;
glGetOutputParameter(out, "gl_FragColor", &color);
```

The implementation of the shader or the exact code to calculate data with the shader may be arbitrary. I just want to perform calculations using GLSL. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how shaders work at all. They take data from one stage of the render pipeline, process it and output data necessary to begin work in the next stage. So typically, you would have vertex data input (vertex shader), which would be transformed into an appropriate vector space, then primitives (i.e. triangles) would be constructed from it (geometry shader, tessellation shaders), then a set of pixels would be rasterized and their color would be computed in a pixel shader. The output of the pixel shader would then be blended with other pixels to produce a final image. The whole point of shaders was to make the render pipeline more flexible, but they are still fundamentally designed to output an image by executing several stages of shaders.

Hacks do exist that allow you to do General Purpose GPU calculations on the GPU using the traditional render pipeline. These hacks often involve things like drawing to a 2x2 texture and performing all of your calculations in a pixel shader. You would then read back the color buffer for the texture you wrote to in the pixel shader.

In short, you can never query a shader for its results, because of the highly-parallel pipelined nature of things. You always have to wait for the pipeline to finish pushing all of the input data through every stage, and then you read back the final image. You can use transform feedback to short-cut the process a little bit, and get the output of a vertex shader, but this probably is not what you want either.

These days, you can skip using Direct3D or OpenGL altogether and directly interface with the stream processors on the GPU in a much more direct way. Instead of using the graphics pipeline in a way it was never really intended to be used, I would suggest you look into **OpenCL** or **CUDA**.

Alternatively, compute shaders (which bypass the traditional render pipeline) are exposed in the very latest implementations of OpenGL and Direct3D (requiring DX11 class hardware and with very limited driver support currently).

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL 4.3 gives you [compute shaders](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/compute_shader.txt).